# Jquery validation only works in subdirectory not root folder

Tags: php, javascript, validation, forms, jquery-validate

I have a contact form on my portfolio site, it was being abused by spammers so I updated it by inserting jquery validation, but for some reason the validation only works correctly when the whole site is loaded in a sub directory not the root public_html folder.

For example my website is located in the root public_html folder.

http://www.jameskirkby.com

On the contact page you can see the error messages without typing.

But if you go to

http://www.jameskirkby.com/test

The validation works fine.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: When is validation broken? I tried it on the 1st link in the home dir and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

**correction**
I tested and your script works fine. I tried entering `na@hotmail` and I got the error message.

But this will not stop spammers. In order to prevent spamming, you need to use something like CAPTCHA.

*And a bit on the side.

Since you are loading all your content in one go, you should consider reducing image file size. It takes a "long" time to load (aprox 4MB).*

Comment: The script works in both sub directories but in the public_html the jquery validation is not working as it should, where as it is fully functional in the /test directory.

In the /test directory on the contact page it doesn't show the paragraph field named "error" unless the validation detects an error

And thanks im looking at implementing captcha and php code to record the senders ip